# AngularJS/Ionic Service Factory Cache

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to "cacheify" my angular service factory. I want it to use the cache to hit the URL only the first time the page is loaded. Then when I browse to my detail page (findById) I want to use the cache. Does this make sense?

Below is what I have right now but I can't figure out a solid way to handle this async. My controller is calling into the service.

```
angular.module('myapp.services', [])

.factory('myservice', function ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {

    var url = '//myurl.com/getawesomeJSON';

    return {

        findAll: function () {

            var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');

            var data = $httpDefaultCache.get(url);
            if (data == null) {
                data = $http.get(url, { cache: true });
            }

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function (id) {

            var data = angular.fromJson($cacheFactory.get('$http').get(url)[1]);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                if (data[i].Id === parseInt(id)) {

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(data[i]);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this since you didn't provide a plunker, but the following should set you in the right direction. You need to make use of promise chaining.

```
angular.module('myapp.services', [])

.factory('myservice', function ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {

    var url = '//myurl.com/getawesomeJSON';

    return {

        findAll: function () {

            var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var data = $httpDefaultCache.get(url);
            if (!data) {
                $http.get(url, { cache: true }).then(function(result){
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function (id) {
           return this.findAll().then(function(data) {
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  if (data[i].Id === parseInt(id)) {
                      return data[i];
                  }
              }
              return $q.reject('Not found'); // id not found
           });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Beyers thanks for the response. But wouldn't I want my findById function to return a promise too? When I call the findAll from the controller it'll need to be handled with a "then" callback. However if I call findById it'll just return the straight result. Shouldn't I be consistent?

Comment: @aherrick `findById()` is in fact returning a promise. Here's a reduced version to show this: `return this.findAll().then(......);`. So it is returning `then()`, and `then()` itself returns a promise. So calling `findById()` returns the promise from `findAll().then()`. The two inner returns are both within the _successCallback_ of `then()` which we know from documentation determines if the promise should be resolved or rejected. The relevant documentation: `This [then()] method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the _successCallback_, _errorCallback_.`

Comment: the problem im having is once the data is cached it is returned in a result like below. when it is not cached it returns differently.http://i.imgur.com/QaF0i1G.jpg

Comment: @aherrick Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like if it is not cached?